# jQuery: infinite loop animation -For a photo slideshow

Tags: jquery, animation, slideshow, infinite-loop

I am trying to create a simple photo slideshow...but I am having problems making it loop infinitely and to go through all the images (and links).

I tried it with a for() function, http://jsfiddle.net/2TPTX/, and also without it, http://jsfiddle.net/2TPTX/1/ .But I still can't get it to work properly.

Can you guys PLEASE help me?

The code it's in the fiddle I provided (http://jsfiddle.net/2TPTX/ or [http://jsfiddle.net/2TPTX/](http://jsfiddle.net/2TPTX/1) but I am including it here as well, for your convenience.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="slideshow">
    <a id="slideshow_lnk" href="www.mysite.com/some_link_1.html">
    <div id="slideshow_img"></div>
    </a>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#slideshow {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}
#slideshow_img {
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:100% 100%;

    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    }
```

jQuery:

```
var $slide = $("#slideshow_img");
var $link = $("#slideshow_lnk");

//$photos Array
var $photos = [['photo', 'link']]; //[0] = Header
$photos[1] = ['http://img510.imageshack.us/img510/2497/54208035.jpg', 'http://www.stackoverflow.com/'];
$photos[2] = ['http://img265.imageshack.us/img265/3355/62320763.jpg', 'http://www.google.com/'];
$photos[3] = ['http://img411.imageshack.us/img411/1237/75707805.jpg', 'http://www.yahoo.com/'];

//Loop variables
$photos.count = $photos.length - 1;
var $fade_time = 3500;
var $i = 1;

function slideshow() {
    $i = ($i > $photos.count ? 1 : $i++);
    $photos.css_url = "url('" + $photos[$i][0] + "')";
    $link.attr("href", $photos[$i][1]);

    $slide.fadeOut($fade_time);
    $slide.css("background-image", $photos.css_url);
    $slide.fadeIn($fade_time);
}

slideshow();
```

Comment: Forgot to mention this: On load, I want `<div id="slideshow_img"></div>`
 to display image 1 AND THEN (after `$fade_time`) to `fadeOut()` and `fadeIn()` with image 2, INSTEAD of `fadeOut()` and then `fadeIn()` with image 1

Answer (score 1):

Here's a JS Fiddle that accomplishes most of what you want, you still probably have a little tweaking to do exactly what you want, but this accomplishes the "infinite looping" as described: http://jsfiddle.net/tGLMF/4/

FYI - in that fiddle i also updated your fadein and fadeout functions, before you had:

```
$slide.fadeOut($fade_time);
$slide.css("background-image", $photos.css_url);
$slide.fadeIn($fade_time);
$timeout = setTimeout(function(){slideshow(slideNumber+1);}, ( $fade_time * 2) + 1000 );
```

i updated that to be:

```
$slide.fadeOut($fade_time, function(){
    $slide.css("background-image", $photos.css_url);
    $slide.fadeIn($fade_time);
    $timeout = setTimeout(function(){slideshow(slideNumber+1);}, ( $fade_time * 2) + 1000 );
});
```

The reason I did that is because animations happen asychronously , so you were calling fadeOut, but while it was fading out, you were then calling fadeIn, which caused some weirdness is what was displayed and when

**Edit to show start with image 1**
New fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/tGLMF/5/

Comment: how can I modify the code to have the div with image 1 and then fade out and in with the next image?

Comment: Omar - you should accept one of the solutions as the answer since your problem was solved.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

jQuery is *asynchronous,* so you need to use its [`.queue()`](http://api.jquery.com/queue/) method to schedule the next step to happen after the animation finishes. I might do it like the below (including some stylistic changes which you can take or ignore).

[Here’s a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2TPTX/3/), let me know if you have any questions.

```
function slideshow($slide, $link, fade_time, images){
    var i = 0;
    function step(next){
        if (i === images.length) {
            i = 0;
        }
        $slide
            .fadeOut(fade_time)
            .queue(function(nextSlide){ return function(next){
                $slide.css("background-image", "url('" + nextSlide.image + "')");
                $link.attr("href", nextSlide.link);
                next();
            }; }(images[i]))
            .fadeIn(fade_time)
            .queue(step);
        i++;
        next();
    }
    $slide.queue(step);
}

var photos = [
    { image: "http://img510.imageshack.us/img510/2497/54208035.jpg", link: "http://www.stackoverflow.com/" },
    { image: "http://img265.imageshack.us/img265/3355/62320763.jpg", link: "http://www.google.com/" },
    { image: "http://img411.imageshack.us/img411/1237/75707805.jpg", link: "http://www.yahoo.com/" }
];

slideshow($("#slideshow_img"), $("#slideshow_lnk"), 3500, photos);
```

Comment: I am a beguinner, as you might had figure out. Where can I learn about what you did with photos array? -I can't understand it: `var photos = [ { image: ..., link: ....... } ]`

Comment: @Omar: You might know that an array is an ordered list of *things*, and the easiest way to create one is by putting the list between square brackets: `[ "one", "two", "three" ]`. These things can be strings, numbers, other arrays, or other *objects*. Most things in JavaScript are objects, but the simplest kind of object is a set of *keys* which have *values*. They are a lot like arrays, except instead of accessing each thing with a number, you access it with its key, which can be any string. (Continued…)

Comment: @Omar: The easiest way to create objects is with curly brackets: `{ name: "Omar", id: 931377 }`. In my code, `photos` is an array which contains three objects. Each of them has an `image` property and a `link` property. You could get at the one link with `photos[0].link`, or `photos[0]["link"]` (in the bracket form, the thing you put in brackets can be any expression, like `photos[0]["li" + "nk"]` or `photos[0][someVariable]`. You can [learn more about object literals here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Core_Language_Features#Object_Literals).

Comment: @Omar: You could use jQuery’s [`.delay()`](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) function, which waits a certain amount of time before running the next thing in an element’s effects queue. Just add `.delay(delayTime)` as a line between `.fadeIn(fade_time)` and `.queue(step)`.

Comment: THANKS!!! Your explanation REALLY helps! BTW, how can I add a var transition_time to the mix? -A time period before the div fades In and Out. (A time period to keep the image before the next one). PS. I like your stylistic changes

Comment: I used your comment to add a delay time between transition. Like this [http://jsfiddle.net/2TPTX/4/](http://jsfiddle.net/2TPTX/4/)?  BTW, I am still having problems iniciating with an image and then switch to the next one -Right now the image is hidden on load

Comment: @Omar: Awesome! I might do that by moving the code that sets the image and link into a function (to avoid duplicating it), calling it right away with the first slide, and then queueing `step` after `delay_time` (starting `i` at 1 instead of 0). [Like this](http://jsfiddle.net/2TPTX/5/).

Comment: WOW! I am really learning with this slideshow, thanks to you and everyone else!!! I am still scratching my head about .queue() -I can't understand the [.queue() documentation](http://api.jquery.com/queue/).... Also I can't make sense out of **(images[i]))**: `.queue(function(nextSlide){ ...  { ... }; }(images[i]))`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5080/discussion-between-omar-and-sidnicious)

Comment: can you please help me? I am trying to add an index to this slide show. -I am still trying to figure out your code at the same time

Comment: Hey, @Omar. The trick would be adding another argument, `i`, to the anonymous function to capture it like you’re capturing `images[i]` as `nextSlide`. Do you want to give that a try? I can point you to the right spots in the code if you’re not sure how to do it.

Comment: how do we start another chat?

Comment: @Omar try [here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6064/discussion-between-omar-and-sidnicious).

Comment: Hey, @Omar. I hung out in that chatroom yesterday but never saw you drop in.

Comment: merry christmas! I am in that chat